# VueJS named routes not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I try to work with named routes in a Vue app.
Exactly the same setup works totally fine in an other Vue project.
If I click on a named router-link, the  just disappears.
If I check the element in the browser, there is an empty comment at the place, where the  section should be.
The console isn't showing any errors.

Has anyone seen something similar?

Thank's for every help!

Code:

index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import Home from '@/components/views/home';
import AskQuestion from '@/components/views/ask-question';
import AddQuestion from '@/components/views/add-question';
import CompleteQuestions from '@/components/views/complete-questions';
import Survey from '@/components/views/survey';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/ask-question',
      name: 'AskQuestion',
      component: AskQuestion
    },
    {
      path: '/add-question',
      name: 'AddQuestion',
      component: AddQuestion
    },
    {
      path: '/complete-questions/:surveyId',
      name: 'CompleteQuestions',
      component: CompleteQuestions
    },
    {
      path: '/survey/:surveyId',
      name: 'Survey',
      component: Survey
    }
  ]
});
```

HTML

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'survey', params: {surveyId: survey.id}}">
   <p class="viewQuestions">View questions</p>
</router-link>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
   <div id="app">
      <navigation></navigation>
      <router-view/>
   </div>
</template>



<script>
   import Navigation from '@/components/generel/navigation';
   export default {
      name: 'app',
      components: {
          Navigation
      }
   };
</script>

<style src="./assets/scss/_general.scss" lang="scss"></style>
```

Comment: You can't route to `survey` when you've name it `Survey`

Comment: it is case sensitive

Comment: Thank's for the hint. I tryed it out but now is just nothing happening when i klick it.

Answer (score 1):

in route config , set history mode and then go to your link and click that LINK , and then go check URL address bar

```
export default new VueRouter({
mode:'history',
......
});
```

for example if you click on this

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'home' }"> Home </router-link>
```

and  your rute is

```
{
  path:'/home',
  component:Home,
  name:'home'
 }
```

if your route workin well , you must see this url in browser address bar

```
 https://localhost/home
```

Comment: When i put it in the history mode, the <router-view> isn't loading at all. But when i test ist without the history-mode, the route works and jumps to the index.

Comment: i will be check